# Is there any way to get the values printed from PHP function without return?

Tags: php, function

I have basically 2 queries related this:

Consider the following PHP function in a class say xyz.php

```
function sendResponse(){
    $car="Lambo";
    echo $car;
}
function sendResponseTwo(){
    $car="Lambo";
    echo $car;
    return $car;
}
function getResponse(){
    //case 1:
    $carName=$this->sendResponse();
    //ABOVE WON'T WORK AS THE FUNCTION RETURNS NOTHING.

    //case 2:
    $carName=$this->sendResponseTwo();
    //THIS WILL PRINT THE NAME OF CAR
}
```

1. In case 1, is there any way to get the echo values by calling the function in another function but **without using return statement**?
2. In case2, is there any way to **stop the values printed by echo statement** (I want only returned value)?

Comment: Output buffering.

Comment: What is that. Any link?

Comment: try these http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: How about instead of making a terrible kludge, you just make the functions return things instead of printing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your both the question lies in `output buffer(ob)`, Hope this will help you out in understanding. Here we are using three function `ob_start()` will start output buffer and `ob_end_clean()` will clean the output of buffer and `ob_get_contents` will give you output as string which is echoed till now. [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.ob-get-contents-examples) will help you better understand `ob_get_contents`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782425)

```
<?php

class x
{
    function sendResponse()
    {
        $car = "Lambo1";
        echo $car;
    }

    function sendResponseTwo()
    {
        $car = "Lambo2";
        echo $car;
        return $car;
    }

    function getResponse()
    {
        //case 1:
        $carName = $this->sendResponse();
        //ABOVE WON'T WORK AS THE FUNCTION RETURNS NOTHING.
        //case 2:
        $carName = $this->sendResponseTwo();
        //THIS WILL PRINT THE NAME OF CAR
    }

}
ob_start();//this will start output buffer
$obj= new x();
$obj->getResponse();
$string=ob_get_contents();//this will gather complete content of ob and store that in $string
ob_end_clean();//this will clean the output buffer
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
$foo->sendResponse();
$response = ob_get_clean();
```

That's why it isn't a practical design in the first place. If you make the function always return the value it's trivial to do both things to your liking:

```php
$response = $foo->sendResponse();
```

```php
echo $foo->sendResponse();
```

```php
<?=$foo->sendResponse()?>
```

*(This last option is shared for illustration purposes and is not intended to open a flame war about short open tags.)*